# Join rows Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a huge table (i.e. 3 million rows) in Google BigQuery. The structure is something like this:

```
name1    attribute1
name2    attribute2
name1    attribute2
```

I'd now like to get a list per name of the attributes that they have. So for the example above, I would want something like this:

```
name1    attribute1, attribute2
name2    attribute2
```

Is this possible with BigQuery (so without having to write any code, just purely as an SQL query)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you use the GROUP_CONCAT function:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(columnNameContainingTheAttribute)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
```

You can learn more about the GROUP_CONCAT function here:
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=FR#aggfunctions

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm not sure about this, I'll check back later, but I think this does give me duplicate attribute names (i.e. duplicates are possible, but if name1 is associated with attribute1 10 times, it should appear 10 times in the concatenated list). From what I've seen so far this isn't entirely accurate, but I'll get back to you on that

Comment: eliminate duplicates with a sub-query: "SELECT name, attrib FROM [table] GROUP BY 1,2". Then wrap that query with the one that does GROUP_CONCAT.